Converting 2.1 channel to 5.1 channel
My current setup that is connected to the TV is Sony HT-S350 (https://www.sony.com/ug/electronics/sound-bars/ht-s350).
I would like to upgrade my setup by adding 2 more speakers at the wall behind the couch.
It seems like my current sound-bar doesn't have support to connect to other speakers by default.
Is there any solution that can work here at a decent price or it is already better to buy a new 5.1 system?

The issue is the decoder. That is the electronics that "splits" the sound into the different channels. A 5.1 has more separate channels than 2.1.
Your choices are to get a true 5.1 by upgrading the hardware or just adding more speakers (assuming the amplifier can drive them).
If your room and speaker placement AND the videos you watch all together give the value, then decide if it is worth it. Old movies - a waste of money. New action movies - you will tell the difference.
I hope this was helpful.
